# Difficulties with div and id arrangement when making my own header bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header bar that looks similar to Bootstrap. If you view this document now the problem is that 'Item 1' is displayed correctly but 'Item 2' is pushed below it, instead of being to the right of it. I thought that by setting "left:80px' to 'Item 2' it would go 80px right of item 1.

Please let me know how to fix this. I was also wondering if I'm doing this in a smart way or if stacking the elements (.items > #item_1) is better. Thanks!

**CSS**

```
/* header, logo, and items */
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #3b5998;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #888888;
}

.items {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #3b5928;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7f7f7;

}

#item_1 {
    width:80px;
    background: fff;
}


#item_2 {
    width: 80px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #3b7328;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--Header and Footer-->
<div id="header">
    <div class="items">
        <div id="item_1"> Item 1 </div>
        <div id="item_2"> Item 2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to change the `display` of the elements to `inline-block`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/hR39b/)

```
.items > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively, you could float the elements or use a flexbox layout.

---

It's worth noting that you can't position a static element (i.e., `position:static` - the default). If you wanted `left: 80px` to work, you could add `position:relative` or `position:absolute` - `fixed` would work too. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/2n2wA/) As the example demonstrates, this isn't really an effective way to line the elements up though. It would be better to either float them or make them inline.

```
#item_2 {
    width: 80px;
    left: 80px;
    background: #3b7328;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why, but when I change item_2 to 'position: relative' it doesn't line up and is below item_1. Any idea?

Comment: @user2469211 All that does is move it `80px` to the right. You would need to add `top:-20px` like this - http://jsfiddle.net/p6CjG/ .. but don't do this, it won't work for dynamic content. You shouldn't hardcode the position like that

Comment: Okay thanks, I will use the inline method then. One more follow up: If I use inspector, 'item_1' and 'item_2' have much less height than 'items'. I want the height to be the same so I can make them clickable later. Do you know what the problem is? Thanks you!

Comment: (It might be the padding from items). Would that be a problem later though if I want 'item_1' clickable for example?

Comment: @user2469211 Yeah, you're probably seeing padding. That shouldn't really be a problem though, here is an example using links - http://jsfiddle.net/2bKxk/ You can still click them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS Fiddle, next time you should set one up. It's very useful for other people to see your issue.

```
<!--Header and Footer-->
<div id="header">
    <div class="items">
        <div id="item_1"> Item 1 </div>
        <div id="item_2"> Item 2 </div>
    </div>
</div>


#item_1 {
width:80px;
color: black;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
```

}

```
#item_2 {
float: left;
width: 80px;
background: #3b7328;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/ws5ew/

Comment: I would recommend using both float left and display: inline-block; BTW. It's a hack that fixes a certain stepping bug in earlier versions of ie.